# Switching from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 16.04, 17.04

As we know, Linux Ubuntu is published in two releases with different release-cycles. The latest ones are: **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus**, one presenting the long-term support version with a less-frequent release-cycle; and **Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus**, one with a faster release-cycle, though with an approximately 18 months guaranteed support period only.

My question is, **is it possible to switch from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus** to **Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus** without the so called *clean install*? At least it is possible from the short-term version to the LST one, but I am not sure if it works the other way around.

I am sorry if I appear a total newbie - which I certainly am - but how could I do this? Terminal-wise speaking, I mean (what commands I have to drive)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Often better to stay with LTS versions for main working system and then allocate another 25GB (or even less) and install the short term ones into that second / (root) partition. Then you can experiment and know your main working system is still fine.

Comment: @karel Thanks! The thread you gave answered to my question perfectly. Too bad though, the system upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak broke my system =( After the very last phase of the upgrade process - the reboot - the system just freezes to the log-in screen. Or more accurately, the system doesn't respond to my typing nor does the mouse navigation work (it recognizes wireless networks though, the clock is in time, it displays the OS version and my username right ..., just it doesn't reply to any inputs). Any recommendations? =(